# Как убрать растягивание блока на всю ширину

Tags: css, css3

Когда я присваиваю ссылке `display: block` или `display: inline-block` или `display: flex`, она всё равно растягивается на всю строку, как это исправить?

Я делаю задний фон и это будет кнопка, но из-за того, что она так растянута, фон тоже растягивается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: код ваш выложите

Comment: Пример, https://jsfiddle.net/u13cp2hm/.  Скорее всего у вас установлена ширина width:100%.

Answer (score 1):

Элементам со стилями `display:block|flex` изначально положено быть растянутыми на всю ширину контейнера, это азы HTML/CSS. Задайте ссылке ширину явно, и отличную от `auto|unset|100%`.

Если бы вы предоставили код для ссылки со стилями до присвоения значения свойству `display`, можно было бы сказать точнее.

Comment: Элементы со стилем display: inline-block не растягиваются на всю ширину, а зависят от содержания

Comment: Вы правы, поправил.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Maref/pen/zYYgxKV Код здесь, напишите, пожалуйста, можете ли вы открыть?

Comment: Ну, в вашем пене если поставить `display:inline-block;`, то он работает как надо.

Answer (score 0):

Если у родителя задан `display: flex; width:100%;`, добавьте свойство `align-items: flex-start;`, чтобы не надо растягивать дочерние элементы